# SQL query to update rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data in a table in following format

```
ID  DocNumber   RevOrder
1   DOC-001     NULL
2   DOC-001     NULL
3   DOC-001     NULL
4   DOC-002     NULL
5   D0C-002     NULL
6   D0C-003     NULL
```

I need to update the `RevOrder` column in to following format

```
ID  DocNumber   RevOrder
1   DOC-001     3
2   DOC-001     2
3   DOC-001     1
4   DOC-002     2
5   D0C-002     1
6   D0C-003     1
```

Logic is: `DocNumber` can be duplicated and the `DocNumber` with the max ID gets the `RevOrder = 1`, next get the `RevOrder = 2` etc... how can I achieve the above scenario?

Comment: You're not expecting the next instance of `DOC_001` to renumber everything are you?  That is, make `id = 1` change `RevOrder` to 4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this `UPDATE` statement based on a `ROW_NUMBER()` over a partition:

```
;WITH UpdateData AS
(
    SELECT 
       ID, DocNumber,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DocNumber ORDER BY ID DESC) AS 'RowNum' 
    FROM dbo.YourTable
)
UPDATE dbo.YourTable
SET RevOrder = RowNum
FROM dbo.YourTable t
INNER JOIN UpdateData ud ON t.ID = ud.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

from SQL Server version 2005 and above, you can use

```
RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY DocNumber ORDER BY ID ASC) AS RevOrder
```

Comment: @marc_s no, it partitions by DocNumber (so the ranking restarts at every change in DocNumber as requested). It behaves pretty much like the solution with ROW_NUMBER() that you proposed, except that RANK() would give the same number to lines with same DocNumber and same ID. Since the ID is unique, I think RANK() will behave exactly like ROW_NUMBER() in this istance. In the more general case, however, your solution with ROW_NUMBER() is more correct.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()` & `PARTITION BY`

```
SELECT  ID,
        DocNumber,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DocNumber ORDER BY DocNumber DESC) AS RevOrder
FROM    @TestTable
```

You can view/test a working example here: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/116435/

Answer (score 0):

I think a row_number() function with partition by clause will work

```
declare @temp as table(
ID int not null
,Doc_Num varchar(20) not null
,RevOrder int null
)
insert into @temp
values
(1,'DOC-001',null)
,(2,'DOC-001',null)
,(3,'DOC-001',null)
,(4,'DOC-002',null)
,(5,'DOC-002',null)
,(6,'DOC-003',null)


select * from @temp


select
t.ID
,t.Doc_Num 
,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by t.Doc_num order by t.ID desc)
from
@temp t
order by t.ID
```